# Check auth with role type in middleware laravel5.5

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, routes, middleware

I know this is very common question but in am stuck in this. I am using Laravel 5.5 and developing an ERP. In ERP some URL only access by Super admin so i create a middleware.

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class CheckAdmin
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        if($user->user_role_id == 1) {
            return $next($request);
        } else {
            return redirect('/');
        }

    }
}
```

I have register this middleware in `Kernel.php`

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckAdmin::class
    ];
```

and usign this middleware in routes

```
$routes = [
    "students" => "StudentsController",
    "teachers" => "TeachersController",
    "courses" => "CoursesController",
    "subjects" => "SubjectsController",
    "colleges" => "CollegesController",
    "branches" => "BranchesController",
];
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth']], function () use ($routes){
    Route::match(["get","post"],'/users','UsersController@index')->middleware('admin');
    Route::get('/users/status/{id}','UsersController@setStatus')->middleware('admin');
    Route::get('/users/delete/{id}','UsersController@delete')->middleware('admin');
    Route::match(["get","post"],'/users/add','UsersController@add')->middleware('admin');
    Route::match(["get","post"],'/users/edit/{id}','UsersController@edit')->middleware('admin');
    Route::match(["get","post"],'/users/view/{id}','UsersController@view')->middleware('admin');


    foreach($routes as $route => $class){
        Route::match(["get","post"],'/'.$route,$class.'@index');
        Route::get('/'.$route.'/status/{id}',$class.'@setStatus');
        Route::get('/'.$route.'/delete/{id}',$class.'@delete');
        Route::match(["get","post"],'/'.$route.'/add',$class.'@add');
        Route::match(["get","post"],'/'.$route.'/edit/{id}',$class.'@edit');
        Route::match(["get","post"],'/'.$route.'/view/{id}',$class.'@view');
    }

    // additions routes
    Route::match(["get","post"],'/courses/assign-subjects','CoursesController@assign_subjects');
    Route::match(["get"],'/courses/already-assign-subjects/{id}','CoursesController@already_assigned_subjects');
});
```

This middleware is not called with `users/*` routes. When i register this `$middleware` in `kernel.php` then its works but `Auth::user()` return `null` every time. So how can i check logged in user role?
I read somewhere that in L5.5 version, `Session` not works in `constructor` then what is the best approach to check user role in middleware.

Comment: Where is the Auth::routes(); ?

Comment: What does your web middleware group look like?

Answer (score 0):

For checking `admin` middleware you can use a nested middleware

```
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'auth']], function () use ($routes){
    Route::match(["get","post"],'/users','UsersController@index')->middleware('admin');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['admin'], function () use ($routes){

    Route::get('/users/status/{id}','UsersController@setStatus')->middleware('admin');
    Route::get('/users/delete/{id}','UsersController@delete')->middleware('admin');

});

    Route::match(["get","post"],'/users/add','UsersController@add')->middleware('admin');
    Route::match(["get","post"],'/users/edit/{id}','UsersController@edit')->middleware('admin');
    Route::match(["get","post"],'/users/view/{id}','UsersController@view')->middleware('admin');


    foreach($routes as $route => $class){
        Route::match(["get","post"],'/'.$route,$class.'@index');
        Route::get('/'.$route.'/status/{id}',$class.'@setStatus');
        Route::get('/'.$route.'/delete/{id}',$class.'@delete');
        Route::match(["get","post"],'/'.$route.'/add',$class.'@add');
        Route::match(["get","post"],'/'.$route.'/edit/{id}',$class.'@edit');
        Route::match(["get","post"],'/'.$route.'/view/{id}',$class.'@view');
    }

    // additions routes
    Route::match(["get","post"],'/courses/assign-subjects','CoursesController@assign_subjects');
    Route::match(["get"],'/courses/already-assign-subjects/{id}','CoursesController@already_assigned_subjects');
});
```

When the admin middleware is outside the `web and auth` it will always return null

Hope this helps